# How do CORS and Access-Control-Allow-Headers work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

I'm trying to make  CORS request POST from `domain.example` to `a.domain.example`.

My JavaScript looks like this

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  url: $('#fileupload').data('path'),
  singleFileUploads: true,
  add: function(e, data){
    data.submit();
  }
});
```

At first I see the OPTIONS route being called like so:

```
Request URL: https://a.domain.example/some/route
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

**OPTIONS REQUEST:**

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Host:a.domain.example
Origin:http://domain.example:3000
Referer:http://domain.example:3000/home
```

**OPTIONS RESPONSE**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://domain.example:3000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
```

That request comes back with a 200 like stated. On my server, I have the same route with `POST` method and this is what I get in return after the `OPTIONS`

```
Request URL:https://a.domain.example/some/route
```

**POST REQUEST**

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryjwr5Pk7WBcfzMdbO
Origin:http://domain.example:3000
Referer:http://domain.example:3000/home
```

and the `POST` request gets canceled/fails.

My question is, do I need to have the access-control-allow-origin on the POST controller as well?

I have a cookie for authorization that has domain `.domain.example` that cookie got sent across once in a request and it's not being sent now. Any idea why that would happen?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes, you need to have the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain.example:3000` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on both the OPTIONS response and the POST response. You should include the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on the POST response as well.

Your OPTIONS response should also include the header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept` to match the requested header.

Comment: Can the protocol be omitted? or can you add one with both http and https?

Comment: protocol can't be omitted, you have to use domain, protocol, and port

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is not allowing anymore. you have to add headers manually.