# Angular: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true

Tags: angular, rest, cordova, ionic-framework, cors

I know there are a lot of questions concerning CORS already but they don't seem to answer my question.

So I have a client app written in Angular which will be used to create a mobile app (with Apache Cordova). The html files and JavaScript files will be loaded from the mobile device.
When I simulate that and I send requests to the REST API server I first got 
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:82`' is therefore not allowed access".
So I added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); in my php REST API Server. I cannot specify a specific domain as the requests will come from the mobile devices.

Now I got to "A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true."

I finally found a solution but I'm not sure it is safe to keep it like this.

In my php REST API Server I added this:

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *, X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
}
```

Please advise on this way of working. If it is not secure or no good at all, can you please tell me how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you need to set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, more info about that header: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24689738/1956540

Comment: Not sure if you know or not, but  "credentials flag is true" doesn't refer to an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header on the response -- it refers to `request.withCredentials = true`.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078676/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-when-credentials-flag-is-true-but/42108718#42108718)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Response should only have the accepted headers in Access-Control-Allow-Headers, don't use wildcard.

As far as it being safe, note the comment from @Jules in this [post about CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1956540):

> Note that sending the HTTP Origin value back as the allowed origin
>   will allow anyone 
>       to send requests to you with cookies, thus potentially stealing a session from a user 
>       who logged into your site then viewed an attacker's page. You either want to send '*' 
>       (which will disallow cookies thus preventing session stealing) or the specific domains 
>       for which you want the site to work.

See also the following for examples:

[Wildcard not accepted in Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719346/1956540)

[Specify headers Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632420/1956540)

---

**Alternative approach**

You can just set the origin header to:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

If you don't need to include cookies in your request remove:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Remove the wildcard from Access-Control-Allow-Headers and add Authorization and then pass that header as part of your request for authorization, instead of passing credentials in a cookie, ex:

```
Authorization: Basic a2lkMT==
```

Also, add the OPTIONS to allowed methods.

Comment: As described "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" does not work. I do need the cookies and combination of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" and sending cookies seems not to be allowed.

Comment: Ok, If you want to use Allow-Credentials then you can't use wildcard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19744754/1956540

Comment: Thank you for your update, it is clear! Though, a few more questions: 1) I guess I need to send the Authorization header on each request, or another token that can be used to identify / recover the session in the backend? 2) I guess I need to store the token in a custom cookie (through JS) or local-storage to survive a browser reload, right? 3) I guess this all is less secure than a HttpOnly cookie to handle the authentication, right? I guess the token might be hacked more easily than with a HttpOnly cookie...