# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" not allowed when credentials flag is true, but there is no Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors, same-origin-policy

Suddenly, seemingly without changing anything in my web app, I started getting CORS errors when opening it in Chrome.  I tried adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.  Then I get this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9091/sockjs-node/info?t= 1449187563637. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:3010' is therefore not allowed access.`

But as you can see in the following image, there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header.

[image]

WTF?  Chrome bug?

My page is loaded at `http://localhost:3010` and that server also uses `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` without problems.  Is there a problem if the two endpoints both use it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**"credentials flag" refers to `XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials` of the request being made, not to an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header.**  That was the source of my confusion.

If the request's `withCredentials` is `true`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` can't be used, even if there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header.

Comment: Yes When making an AJAX call with the parameter withCredentials: true, the response header should have the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true. Consequently, this headers does not allow for the use of Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*

For more information, on the withCredential parameter and the response header look at this article:

http://www.ozkary.com/2015/12/api-oauth-token-access-control-allow-credentials.html

Comment: Same here, thought the error message was referring to the header. Wasn't aware of the `withCredentials` flag. Weird.

Comment: I filed a chrome bug about the message being confusing and if I remember correctly they took it seriously

Comment: This is [the bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=566239#c8) and I still see the confusing message. I've raised the issue internally.

Comment: @DanDascalescu cool, thanks!  it looks like they're waiting for your response on that thread

Comment: there's a way to succesfully do a CORS request with credentials and access-control-allow-origin=* Please read my comment

Comment: @Andy so your answers explains the problem but does not say how to actually solve the issue. Would you please have more insight on that? thanks

Comment: I am also face same issue in this call a other server file using ajax but after ajax calling its give same error I have already added the all require headers in response 
will we add any heder in calling page also?

Answer (score 9):

Requests `withCredentials:true`, on a server configured with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` **CAN be used**, but you will need some more extra config on your server:

Using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` on the server, it will not allow access to any resource (that requires credentials) on any xhr CORS request.

**Workarounds:**

1. Make that remote resource on the server accesible without credentials
   ( and use `xhr.withCredentials = false` )
2. Create a rewrite rule on
       the server, to modify the response header
       `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` to the request's origin. You can
       also apply this rewrite under certain criteria, for example, if
       request is using certain port or it comes from a list of whitelisted
       domains.

Here is some [article that explains how to do this on a IIS server](https://kamranicus.com/posts/2016-03-06-cors-multiple-origins-iis), but you can do this in many other servers:

PS: in case of using credentials, you will also need the following header on your server's response: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true`

PS2: only 1 value is allowed to "access-control-allow-origin" paramenter. If you try to use for instance two domains: domain1.com domain2.com, it won't work.

Comment: Thats not right. Two domains are not work, and Wildcard with use credentials is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved same problem** by using these steps..

1) disable your chrome extension "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin"

2) add these into your service

var xhr = new ();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

Comment: " the servlet " ? (I'm still new-ish to front-end web dev, so I have no idea what that is in this context.) Thanks.

Comment: mistake.not " the servlet "..it's your service

Comment: thanks , worked for me just after disabling chrome extension "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: Same solution worked for me after disabling chrome extension.

Comment: this won't help for production, you can't tell users to disable such extension

Comment: @Alberto, you can tell because this extension is a developer tool. Each developer needs to know his environment. You are focusing on your software development, not on developer's environments.
The end users will not see this error, but the developers who have this extension YES.
My humble opinion.

Comment: Not exactly. "credentials flag" refers to XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials of the request being made, not to an Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header. If you are using * for Allow-origin, you wont be able to send any credentials along your request. The mentioned solution will only work for testing a development.