# Angular / Node CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, cors

I am building a web application with node js on server side and angular on client.

I am running the server on different domain and client on other domain.

My server side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
var request = require('request');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
             "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  next();
});

app.get('/api/hello', function(req, res){
  var data = {'message': 'Server is running'}
  res.jsonp(data);
});

http.listen(5000);
```

and on the client side (Angular).

```
angular.controller('myController', function($state, $http){
  $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/hello').success(function(response, status) {
    console.log(responce);
  }).error( function(error, status) {
    console.log(error)
  });
});
```

My Server is running on port 5000 and my client on port 4000 on different domains.

When I send the above request from client, I get below error in browser console,

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/api/hello.  Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:  A wildcard
>   '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when
>   the credentials flag is true.  Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

I have same problem with the ionic app too.

What could be the reason behind this?

I am accessing these API's from multiple domains and from different applications like mobile and web.

Comment: A pre-flight request uses the `'options'` verb instead of `'get'` so you need a handler for that.  There is something about the specific request you're making (probably custom headers) that forces the use of the `'options'` preflight.

Comment: try being domain specific with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: See [How to enable CORS in Express](http://justindavis.co/2015/08/31/CORS-in-Express/) for `OPTIONS` support.

Comment: @jfriend00 I looked into your first comment, but I don't set any custom headers.

Comment: @techie_28 I am accessing this server apis from multiple domains. So, I am not being domain specific.

Comment: Well, there are several things that can trigger the use of the OPTIONS preflight.  Your error message makes it appear that is being triggered, but your server does not support it so you are denied access.  That's your first issue to solve.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests for details on what can trigger it or implement support for it.

Comment: @nitinmegamind I suggested that for the testing purpose only.The error is self describing.Wildcard `*` is disallowed in case you use credentials.

Comment: @techie_28 I have added a domain specific too, but still the same error.

Comment: @nitinmegamind I expected error to say something else in that case.You mentioned the specific domain instead of a `*`?

Comment: I mentioned **http://localhost:4000** instead of *.

Comment: @nitinmegamind seems you are facing this possibly : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Comment: @techie_28 I have tried with a server too. Facing the same problem.

Comment: @nitinmegamind both of them are on a valid server & are you using wildcard still?If so try with specific value in there for once.Is there no change in the console error?

Comment: @nitinmegamind are you really using credentials anywhere?

Comment: @techie_28 I am not using credentials. But I am using token for some apis to authenticate the user. Is that the problem?

Comment: @nitinmegamind check this..You will have to set `withCredentials` to false on your client side.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078676/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-when-credentials-flag-is-true-but

Answer (score 1):

you can use `cors` as like as given below:

**install cors module**

`npm install --save cors`

**server code**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var cors = require('cors');


 var app = express();     

 app.use(cors());

 // others code
```

**Angular**

```
angular.controller('myController', function($state, $http){

   $http
     .get('http://localhost:5000/api/hello')
     .then(function(response) {
          console.log(responce);
       }, function(error, status) {
          console.log(error)
       });
});
```

Comment: Still I get the CORS error. This solution didn't work for me. Tried doing the same in angular. But no success.

Answer (score 0):

In that error, it appears as though your `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header might be to returned as true? What headers does your response contain?

Try adding `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);` when you're adding your headers and see if that solves that particular error.

Also, is there a reason why you've included the http.createServer(app) code? ExpressJS apps are typically started by calling `app.listen` directly like so which could well be the issue.

```
app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 5000!');
});
```

Comment: Your preflight is reaching the server (or a server somewhere) as it is receiving some form of header from the preflight request (the OPTIONS request). What headers does this request receive? You can find this information in your inspector. What does visiting `http://localhost:5000/api/hello`directly in the browser return as well?

Comment: Reqeust Headers:   OPTIONS /api/hello HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4000
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: Response Headers:   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,PUT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 17
ETag: W/"11-UunX7iLX/fl1v0lmwRZzlA"
Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 08:38:49 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Yeah, not sure. That all looks fine. Only other thing I'd suggest is checking if you have any cookies or auth based stuff cached in your browser from other projects that the browser might be trying to send? Otherwise not sure... Good luck otherwise!

Comment: @IanBelcher this seems to be a "using localhost as origin problem".. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Comment: @techie_28: I myself haven't used locahost for development for some time now, but that link looks like it most likely could be the cause. Good to keep that in mind for future.

Answer (score 0):

in routes i made a file named as corsheaders.js 
which contains

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if (allowedHosts.indexOf(req.headers.origin) > -1) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PUT');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    }
    next();
};
```

here allowedHosts is an array which contains the domain which i am allowing and in app.js i have use this file as

```
app.use(require('./routes/corsheaders'));
```