# The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cors

My application is working fine in IE browser, **But it's not working in Chrome browser due to `CORS` issue.**

The issue is

> Failed to load http://localhost:52487/api/Authentication/: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I am using angular 2 in front-end  and using Asp.net core 1.0 in back-end. I have tried

This is my startup code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p =>
        {
            p.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
    services.AddOptions();
    // Add our Config object so it can be injected
    services.Configure<Data>(Configuration.GetSection("Data"));

    services.Configure<COCSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("COCSettings"));

    services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));

    AppSettings.ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnectionString"];

    // *If* you need access to generic IConfiguration this is **required**
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

    // Injecting repopsitories with interface
    AddServices(services);

    // Add Json options
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandling));
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(GetNoCache));
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

this is how I am calling the API from UI(angular) side

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
}

GetMaintainCOC(FYONId) {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'GetCertificationofConformity?FYONId=' + FYONId, { withCredentials: true })
    .map(responce => <any>responce.json())
    .catch(error => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: "tried some of the ... previous answers" - What did you try exactly? Did you try setting a white list like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803394/cors-credentials-mode-is-include), what part of that solution did not work for you?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking (it is clear what problem you have - you disagree with CORS policy - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i) - please clarify what you want to achieve... Sounds like not using Chrome is the only option (at least for some time till other browsers align with the same policy) as you explicitly `p.AllowAnyOrigin()`...

Comment: @Tewr Added withCredential true in `http.get()`. But I am didn't see any question related with this exact problem. So I have manually tried with some suggestions from stack overflow and google.

Comment: `AllowAnyOrigin` just plain isn't going to work if you want this to work with credentials. So don't set that - specify specific origins.

Comment: I got it. But i don't know is this exact solution. But it is working now in all browsers. :) Please check my answer :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's not exactly true, because `AllowAnyOrigin` does not necessary translate to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. ASP.NET knows that "*" cannot be used with credentials, so will use request origin instead if you specify `AllowCredentials`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is working, when I am calling `AllowCredentials()` inside of `AddPolicy`

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p =>
                {
                    p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

I got this key of idea from
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" not allowed when credentials flag is true, but there is no Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078676/access-control-allow-origin-not-allowed-when-credentials-flag-is-true-but)

### What I understood

> I am using `{ withCredentials: true }` in angular `http` service call. So I guess I should use `AllowCredentials()` policy  in `CORS` service.

Comment: AllowAnyOrigin does not work with AllowCredentials.  need to have specfiic origin

Answer (score 2):

Well you appear to have it solved, but here's the simple answer.

If you set the `withCredentials` flag in the request definition, cookies etc. will be passed in the request. Otherwise they won't be passed.

If your server returns any `Set-Cookie` response headers, then you must **also** return the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` response header, otherwise the cookies will **not be created** on the client. And if you're doing that, you need to **also** specify the EXACT origin in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, since `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is not compatible with credentials.

So do this:

- Pass withCredentials in request
- Pass `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <value-of-Origin-request-header>` response header
- Pass `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` response header

Answer (score 0):

Even with `AllowCredentials()` I was getting the error after publishing it to Azure App Service. Issue was I had wildcard (*) under CORS section in my App Service. I removed it and error was gone.

[image]