# How to solve the CORS error in Laravel + Nuxt.js

Tags: laravel, cors, nuxt.js, endpoint

I am installing the old project, which is made by Nuxt.js (frontend) and Laravel (backend) on my local.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/user' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

This is the issue that I faced to run the project.

Frontend configuration for the request(nuxt `nuxt.config.js`).

```
user: {
    url: '/api/user',
    method: 'get',
    propertyName: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}
```

Backend configuration (Laravel `config/cors.php`)

```
'paths' => ['api/*'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

I tried to find the solution by googling but I didn't find the correct solution.

[withCredetials is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)

[CORS: credentials mode is 'include'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803394/cors-credentials-mode-is-include)

[The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861290/the-value-of-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-the-response-must-not-b)

So, I want someone to help me in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way in your laravel app:

```
php artisan serve --host YOUR_LOCAL_IP
```

YOUR_LOCAL_IP is your ip that can access with `ifconfig` command in linux and `ipconfig` in windows.

Finally you should request to `YOUR_LOCAL_IP:PORT/api`

Comment: I am running it on windows 10.