# Problems with Angular, CORS and Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, post, cors

I have a simple project based on @RestController and AngularJS.
I can send GET requests from Angular to @RestController but i could not send POST request. I have an error in browser console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/add. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

My @RestController:

```
@RestController
public class AngularController {
    //@Autowired
  //  PhraseService phraseService;
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void add(@RequestBody String str){
        logger.info("Added");
        logger.info(str);

    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void angularController(){;
        logger.info("Request!");
    }
}
```

Here is my CORS filter:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

My AngularJS controller:

```
function addController($scope, $http){
    $scope.url = 'http://localhost:8080/add';
    $scope.addPhrase = function(){
        $http.post($scope.url, {"data": $scope.value});
    }
}
```

And index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="server.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="addController">
    <form>
    <input type="text" np-model="value"/>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addPhrase()">Send!</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to solve this problem with header: "Content-Type": "application/json" but it gave me Bad request error.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630231/how-do-cors-and-access-control-allow-headers-work) out, you probably need to add `"Content-Type"` to the `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also consider using the native CORS support available in the upcoming [Spring Framework 4.2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/15/spring-framework-4-2-rc3-released-ga-on-july-30) release. See [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) for more details.

By default, it is configured to automatically accept all the headers, so it should work as soon as you enable CORS support with `CrossOrigin` annotation or with Java config.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 4.2 and further releases, there is a first class support for CORS out-of-the-box. The details can be found on this [page](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).

In the Spring classes annotated with RESTController, @CrossOrigin annotation can be used. Following code represents the same:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
public class AngularController {
}
```

In the above code, localhost:3000 represents Angular app URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add additional options in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Here are the options usually used:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```