# How to include a JSF page inside angular application

Tags: angular, jsf

I have two applications, one made in JSF and another in angular.
I am trying to invoke the JSF application from an angular application.
I have got one solution to solve the situation but searching if it is good or there is a better solution to the problem.

The one solution/experiment which I tried was using Iframe.

In this approach, I am embedding my jsf application in my current angular app.

The example code as follows:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/jsftestapp">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

With the help of this I able to invoke the JSF application.

But I have concerns regarding points like security in Iframe, or how can we pass parameters from the angular app to jsf when needed or vice versa when required ?

Answer (score 0):

This way you don't really "embed" it. You just load it in an iframe. All security issues are the same as with all webapps from different domains/urls etc... The solution would be in configuring/using 'CORS' correctly

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
- [Problems with Angular, CORS and Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982907/problems-with-angular-cors-and-spring)