# CORS issue with angular $http.post - successful requests result in errors with status 0

Tags: angularjs, http, cors

I'm using angular to POST to an authentication endpoint; on the server side, I can see the request succeed, and proper CORS headers are set.  Angular's origin is `http://localhost:9000`

On the server side, preflight `OPTIONS` requests always get a `200` back, so that seems OK.

On the client side, the `$http.post` always fails with an error code of 0, which from other research suggests something is still wrong with CORS.   I've read the spec and tried a number of other answers, yet something is still missing.

Angular POSTs like this:

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login',
        data: {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
         /* etc. etc. */
    }, function (response) {
        /* This always triggers, with response.status = 0 */
        console.log("ERROR: " + response.data);
        console.log("Status: " + response.status);
        console.log("Status text: " + response.statusText);
        console.log("Headers: " + response.headers);

        $scope.error = 'Something went wrong...';
    });
```

Using curl to debug what the server is sending back, this is it:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Set-Cookie: ua_session_token=(blahblah); Path=/
< Location: /
< Vary: Accept
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 23
< Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 15:08:17 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
```

This is why I'm at a loss, as per the specification, the server seems to be doing the right thing?

Here's what the server gets from the client in terms of request headers:

```
HEADER host localhost:3000
HEADER content-type application/json;charset=UTF-8
HEADER origin http://localhost:9000
HEADER content-length 38
HEADER connection keep-alive
HEADER accept application/json, text/plain, */*
HEADER user-agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9
HEADER referer http://localhost:9000/
HEADER accept-language en-us
HEADER accept-encoding gzip, deflate
```

**UPDATE** tried something else with no luck, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630231/how-do-cors-and-access-control-allow-headers-work).  It would seem `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is case-sensitive, and angular is sending on the request `accept, origin, content-type`.  I tweaked the server to parrot back the same, with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3336)?

Comment: I did come across that in background research. When you do `OPTIONS` pre-flight to the server, in my case you get a 200 (not a 500 as in that post) and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is on that `OPTIONS` preflight request.  So I read that whole thread, but it doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: That thread does mention a JSON payload from the server.  In my case, there is **no json payload**; when auth succeeds the client gets an auth token and a redirect to a protected resource.  Is the lack of a response body (just redirect) a possible cause here?  It seems it still wouldn't explain the status being 0, since from the server it's clearly 200.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after applying my head to my keyboard for several hours, I've fixed it.

The answer seems to be that angular really doesn't like getting redirects in response to `POST`.   When I changed the server endpoint to return just a plain auth token as text (the same token it was setting as a cookie anyway) rather than returning a redirect, the angular `POST` started working like a charm and falling through to the success handler.

Not sure I got deep enough into this to know why angular was behaving in that way; by playing around with it I found that if the redirect the server sent was to a nonexistent (404) URL that this could be replicated, **EVEN IF** the original POST returned that valid redirect.