# Invalid preflight CORS request because the header "content-type" is not in :allow_headers

Tags: angular, elixir, phoenix-framework

I currently have an Angular 2 front end and Phoenix backend. For some reason I can do GET requests just fine. In Phoenix I have the code in `endpoint.ex`

```
plug Corsica, origins: "*"
```

This allows me to do GET requests however, when I try POST reqests to the same address my backend spits out the error

```
Invalid preflight CORS request because the header "content-type" is not in :allow_headers
```

I'm not sure if I need to be sending something from my front end or if I need to enable something from the backend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630231/how-do-cors-and-access-control-allow-headers-work Either don't send the `content-type` or add it to allowed headers on the server.

Comment: Try `plug Corsica, origins: "*", allow_headers: ["content-type"]`.

Comment: @Dogbert your solution worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to add the headers you want to be in `access-control-allow-headers` to the `:allow_headers` option of Corsica plug.

```
plug Corsica, origins: "*", allow_headers: ["content-type"]
```

> `:allow_headers` - a list of headers (as binaries). Sets the value of the `access-control-allow-headers` header used with preflight requests. Defaults to `[]` (no headers are allowed).

[Source](https://hexdocs.pm/corsica/Corsica.html)